# how to use mysqli_fetch_array with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

so everyone told me to use prepared statements, but i have no idea what to do now.

```
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM search WHERE `name2` LIKE '?' AND `approved`='approved'");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $name);

/* execute prepared statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

That is my code, how do i make an array from it like

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

from non-prepared

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see you are deciding to use PDO!

```
//using MySQL
//refer here for reference http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;port=xxx;dbname=xxx', $username, $password)

//write query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE `name2` LIKE '?' AND `approved`='approved'";

//tell query what to replace ? marks with
$fill_array = array($name); // one item in array for the one ? in $sql above

//send query to DB for preparation
$prepare = $pdo->prepare($sql);

//send variables to DB, DB will bind them to the proper place and execute query
$prepare->execute($fill_array);

//get your array. I personally recommend PDO::FETCH_ASSOC but you are using ARRAY
$result = $prepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ARRAY);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($result, true).'</pre>';
```

Voila!

Please not that you will have to write code to escape $name and check for things like % signs and underscores because if someone literally types in % then the LIKE statement will return all records where approved='approved'

Comment: how do you find the number of rows such as mysqli_num_rows from before

Comment: and what is the port??

Comment: Default mysql port is 3306

Comment: The documentation states that for SELECT queries a lot of databases simply don't support a direct row count function. As far as counting the number of rows is concerned you can simply count the items in the $result so you would do this: $num_rows = count($result);

Comment: I would bet you that mysql_num_rows() does something similar on the back-end

Comment: does not find anything

Comment: it says 0 results found but the database has lots of rows and before PDO it worked fine

Comment: You will have to debug your connection settings and make sure that everything in 'mysql:host=xxx;port=xxx;dbname=xxx' is being set correctly. You will also have to check your php.ini file and make sure PDO is enabled. Is your PHP script returning any errors on-screen? Make sure to set error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of your page to make sure you see all errors.

Comment: PDO is tougher but once it works you won't believe you ever lived without it. You are a programmer (i assume), are you going to let a debugging issue beat you? Took me 3 days to learn and implement it.

Comment: MySQLi and PDO are 2 different things.